# Is there a tax form that reports deductible contributions to a 529 plan?

Tags: united-states, 529-plan

All 529 plan contributions are not deductible at the Federal level, therefore the IRS doesn't seem to have a form used to report the contributions. However, several states (like mine, Oklahoma) allow the contributions to be deducted for state taxes.

Is there a form that the 529 administrator should generate for me to report the contributions on my state tax return (similar to form 5498 for IRAs)? Or is it okay to just consider the "Contributions for 2020: $XX" from my online account as sufficient proof that I made the contributions?

Comment: Usually state tax forms will have a specific line for things they allow deductions for that the Feds do not - how does Oklahoma ask you to record this in their 1040 equivalent?

Comment: @Joe It goes on Line 4 of Oklahoma's Schedule 511-C. But I think the OP is asking if they can expect a form from the administrator of the 529 plan. Like the way you get a W-2 to know what goes in the wages box on the 1040, rather than relying on the year-to-date value of your last paycheck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did some more digging after reading the comments and @Doug Deden's [answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/137478/71269). Everything I found says that I will not receive a tax form for contributions from the 529 administrator. This could be different for other states. I think the best way to verify what is required to report the contributions for the tax deduction is to look at the state's equivalent of the IRS 1040 (tax return form).

For Oklahoma specifically, the [Schedule 511-C instructions](https://www.ok.gov/tax/documents/511Pkt-20.pdf) elaborate on reporting 529 contributions:

> Provide proof of your contribution including the name of the
> beneficiary and the account number

As long as the document with "Contributions for 2020: $XX" also includes the beneficiary and account number I should be fine.

Answer (score 4):

I've never received one. The instructions I've found from my plan administrator and others indicate that while you'll get a 1099-Q reporting any withdrawals, you won't get a special form reporting your contributions.

Rather, you just use the information from your year-end statement -- something like `2020 Contributions: $xxxx` -- on your state income tax return, if appropriate.

Sources:

- https://www.savingforcollege.com/article/529-plans-tax-return
- https://support.wealthfront.com/hc/en-us/articles/213257506-What-tax-documents-should-I-expect-to-receive-for-my-529-account-
- https://www.brightstart.com/bright-start-top-year-end-questions/

Answer (score 0):

https://www.taxformfinder.org/forms/2021/2021-oklahoma-form-511ef.pdf

The instructions on the 511EF form (page 2 on the link) tell you where to send documentation.

In the past, after e-filing, I've printed off a summary of the contributions, as well as "page 1" from the Oklahoma 529 end of year statements, and sent that in.  I've never had a problem doing it that way.