# MESP Tax forms for years with only contributions

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, 529-plan, michigan

I started two 529 funds for my children in the 2023 calendar year and want to claim the contributions from my Michigan State Income tax.  But I was looking on the MESP site and can't find any tax forms - there is this note on one of the forms pages

> No tax forms were found. Form 1099-Q will only be issued if a withdrawal was processed during the calendar year. For information on contributions, please view the statements and confirmations.

I get why they would issue a tax form for withdrawals but it seems weird that they don't issue one for contributions? The [Michigan 2023 Schedule Instructions](https://www.michigan.gov/taxes/-/media/Project/Websites/taxes/Forms/2023/2023-IIT-Forms/Schedule-1-Instructions.pdf?rev=cce683846952405680e699d2336f4e88&hash=5368C3372752B4780D2DF67653078051) call out MESP contributions for Line 17 - are they just trusting us at our word for what those contributions are? How are those getting reported to the proper tax authority?

Comment: I assume it's just like my state (OK). No tax form, just need some sort of document: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/137459/is-there-a-tax-form-that-reports-deductible-contributions-to-a-529-plan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> are they just trusting us at our word for what those contributions are?

Yes - and if you get audited then you'll have to back up the claim.

Since *anyone* can mail a check to your 529 there's no practical way to track contributions in a way that would be meaningful to the IRS (i.e. by SSN). So it's trust-but-verify.

*Distributions*, on the other hand are easier to tie to the recipient, so an IRS form is more feasible.

Answer (score 2):

529 contributions are not tax deductible for federal tax purposes, so there's no form for contributions.

Keep your bank statements to substantiate the deduction if audited.